# Adding arrays to vector in for loop with random_shuffle

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm trying to add  int-array permutations into vector in for loop, but when I leave a loop, every vector element is the same.

```
task_number = 6;
vector<int*> P_0;
int* order = new int[task_number];
for (int k = 0; k < task_number; k++)
            order[k] = k;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    random_shuffle(order, order+task_number);
    cout << endl;
    P_0.push_back(order);
    for (int j = 0; j < task_number; j++)
        cout << P_0[i][j] << " ";
}
//////////////////////////////////////
cout << endl<<endl;

std::vector<int*>::iterator it;
for (it = P_0.begin(); it != P_0.end(); ++it)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < task_number; j++)
        cout << (*it)[j] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

output:

```
1 3 0 2 5 4
1 4 5 3 2 0
1 3 5 4 0 2

1 3 5 4 0 2
1 3 5 4 0 2
1 3 5 4 0 2
```

what is the problem? I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to allocate k number of times the integer pointer. If you change the code as follows it will work

```
int task_number = 6;
vector<int*> P_0;


for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    int* order = new int[task_number];
    for (int k = 0; k < task_number; k++)
            order[k] = k;
    random_shuffle(order, order+task_number);
    cout << endl;
    P_0.push_back(order);
    for (int j = 0; j < task_number; j++)
        cout << P_0[i][j] << " ";
}
//////////////////////////////////////
cout << endl<<endl;

std::vector<int*>::iterator it;
for (it = P_0.begin(); it != P_0.end(); ++it)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < task_number; j++)
        cout << (*it)[j] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All three elements of the vector keep the same pointer to the first element of the dynamically allocated array

```
P_0.push_back(order);
```

that is the value of `order` itself was not changed.

Instead of using a dynamically allocated array you could use a vector of vectors declared like

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> P_0;
```